# Keep Material Slide Toggle pegged on or off without using disabled

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, slide

The requirements for my Angular 4 application require the mat-slide-toggle's to stay on (in color) or stay off in some cases. Normally the disabled tag would be used for this case it is preferred in this case to keep the toggle in the same state and throw up a snackbar alerting the user.

My approach was just to pass in the change event and toggle the button back to its pre-clicked state after the function is called. However, it seems to only work for the first click and then the user seems to be free to toggle as they wish. Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Edit: An example of what I am doing is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bspml8-qtafs2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop the click event from reaching MatSlideToggle's click handler. You can do that by adding your own click handler and calling preventDefault() on the event:

```
<mat-slide-toggle (click)="$event.preventDefault()" ...>...</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Comment: but the keypress spacebar button can change toggled value. I call preventDefault in event keypress if keyCode == spacebar (32). it seems not to work.

Comment: I think because of class name of css. The mat-slide-toggled has remove mat-checked class name even though I call $event.preventDefault(). So that why I can toggle the component

Comment: Use `keydown` instead of `keypress`.

Comment: it is the same to keypress, you can try it with the link of the question. You use key spacebar to toggle on off without notification even though already called preventDefault()

Comment: I tried it with the link in the question - works fine with `keydown`.

Comment: doesnt work on material 16.2.3